# How to dump all of our images from a VARBINARY(MAX) field in SQL Server 2008 to the filesystem?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinary

I have a table which has an `IDENTITY` field and a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field in it. Is there any way I could dump the content of each `VARBINARY(MAX)` field to the *filesystem* (eg. `c:\temp\images`)?

#### Table schema:

```
PhotoId INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY
Image VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
DateCreated SMALLDATETIME
```

#### Output:

```
c:\temp\images\1.png
c:\temp\images\2.png
c:\temp\images\3.png
... etc...
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured it out thanks to [this post](http://madhuottapalam.blogspot.com/2008/08/creating-files-from-images-stored-in.html) ...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @IdThumbnail INTEGER,
        @MimeType VARCHAR(100),
        @FileName VARCHAR(200),
        @Sqlstmt varchar(4000)


DECLARE Cursor_Image CURSOR FOR
    SELECT a.IdThumbnail
    FROM tblThumbnail a
    ORDER BY a.IdThumbnail

OPEN Cursor_Image
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Image INTO @IdThumbnail

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Generate the file name based upon the ID and the MIMETYPE.
        SELECT @FileName = LTRIM(STR(@IdThumbnail)) + '.png'

        -- Framing DynamicSQL for XP_CMDshell            
        SET @Sqlstmt='BCP "SELECT OriginalImage 
                      FROM Appian.dbo.tblThumbnail 
                      WHERE IdThumbnail = ' + LTRIM(STR(@IdThumbnail)) +
                      '" QUERYOUT c:\Temp\Images\' + LTRIM(@FileName) + 
                      ' -T -fC:\Temp\ImageFormatFile.txt'
        print @FileName
        print @sqlstmt

        EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlstmt
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Image INTO @IdThumbnail
    END

CLOSE Cursor_Image
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Image
```

Please note -> u need to have a format file, for the BCP command. This is the content of the file and i've placed it in c:\Temp (as noted in the BCP commandline above).

```
10.0
1
1       SQLIMAGE            0       0       ""   1     OriginalImage                      ""
```

Final note about that format file .. there HAS TO BE A NEW LINE AFTER THE LAST LINE. otherwise u'll get an error.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (for me) would be to write a little .NET application that dumped the varbinary fields to a file.

If you are opposed to working in .NET, then you should (I've not tested this) be able to create a new column of type "VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM".  Be sure you also have a the corresponding "ROWGUIDCOL" column.  Then you can (in theory) do something like:

UPDATE table
SET  varfilestream_col = varbinary_col

Hope that works for ya.

Comment: So if i have a new 'filestream' column, how to i export that content files using t-sql instead of making a .NET application?

Comment: Upvoting it just to get it off the "Unanswered" screen.