# MS SQL Server 2005, write varbinary to file system

Tags: sql-server, pdf, varbinary

Using just an sql query is it possible to write the contents of a varbinary cell to the file system? I have a column that stores pdf s as and for some quick testing I'd like to write out the pdfs to the filesystem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar Question Here.

[How to dump all of our images from a VARBINARY(MAX) field in SQL Server 2008 to the filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613154/how-to-dump-all-of-our-images-from-a-varbinarymax-field-in-sql2008-to-the-files)

You'll need to iterate through each row and perform a BCP (BulkCopy) Dump of each varbinary field to the filesystem